# SUPEE-9767 for Magento 1.9.3.3

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

I wanna install some patches for my magento 1.9.3.3, but i didn't find SUPEE-9767 in https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.9.3.3 is the latest release, as such it includes all released patches. If you look on the download page under the download for 1.9.3.3, you can see that it lists the included patches, which includes SUPEE-9767.

So basically you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

In your browser pull up

```
https://magento.com/tech-resources/download
```

Click on the "Release Archive" tab and scroll down to

```
Magento Community Edition Patches - 1.x
```

You will find the patch there.

Comment: As it stands, there are no patches for 1.9.3.3.

Comment: Correct, I just was just clarifying where to find the patch.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.9.3.3 is the latest release. you don not need for SUPEE-9767 patch